# What Are the Options for TextMate 2's indentOnPaste, or How Do I Fully Disable it?

Tags: textmate, textmate2

Typing in TextMate 2 used to be an adventure in indentation frustration, now cured by a global disableIndentCorrections setting. Pasting code, however, always seems to end up in a very wrong indentation level. It's making me crazy.

I've come across the following settings:

```
{   disableIndentCorrections = :true;
    indentOnPaste = 'default';
}
```

And in searching I've seen `indentOnPaste` set to `'default'` or `'simple'`, both of which have code jumping multiple tabs to the right when it really, really should not.

Anyone know how to disable indentation on paste?

Answer (score 2):

1. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>⌃</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> to enter the Bundle Editor.
2. Select `Text`➜`Settings`➜`Disable Indention Correction`.
3. In the right pane, remove the contents of the `Scope Selector` field to let these settings apply globally.

By default, the contents of the selected item should read as follows:

```
{   disableIndentCorrections = :true;
    indentOnPaste = 'simple';
}
```

so there is no need to modify them.

Comment: I just followed these steps and it worked to stop auto-indenting when I pasted text.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you.:)

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the r9283 release notes:

---

Split disableIndentCorrections into two settings:

The disableIndentCorrections setting disables the (aggressive) indent corrections that TextMate does while you type.

An additional indentOnPaste setting controls how to indent when pasting and can be set to:

1. `simple` — this is the indent behavior which was previously implied when setting disableIndentCorrections. It indents the paste to the position of the caret and works well for Python.
2. `disable` — the text is inserted as-is without indenting it.
3. «unset» — indent the paste based on the indent patterns of the current scope.

Comment: Good eye on catching that in the release notes. Unfortunately, indentOnPaste = 'disable' does not actually disable needless indents when pasting.

Comment: This solution did not work for me either. Even removing the increaseIndentPattern from the grammar completely had no effect on the 'ident on paste' behavior. I'm using v2.0-alpha.9495.